# How can I check whether the build is triiggered by timer or by the user?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

How can I check whether the build is triiggered by timer or by the user.

I have a build which is scheduled to run and there times I run it manually also. Can I get who started the run from a variable or something in the same run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use "BUILD_CAUSE" variable for getting the information about who initiated the run

Comment: for [jenkins-pipeline] you may use `currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()` (see https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/get-build-cause/getBuildCause.groovy for more details)

Comment: It should be mentioned that this variable is not set by default. I had to install the "Environment Injector Plugin" before the variable was available.

Answer (score 3):

There is Jenkins [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin) which allows you to identify, among others, how the build was triggered.

In the features section of the link above you can see:

> Build Cause Run 
>   the build step depending on the cause of the build e.g. triggered by timer, user, scm-change,...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a shared pipeline library, create a file startedByTimer.groovy:

```
@NonCPS
def call() {
    boolean startedByTimer = false

    def buildCauses = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()

    for (buildCause in buildCauses) {
        if ("${buildCause}".contains("hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger\$TimerTriggerCause")) {
            startedByTimer = true
        }
    }

    return startedByTimer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Bachu already answered build cause is available in ${BUILD_CAUSE} environment variable.
Moreover for each trigger type is corresponding environment variable which can be interpreted as boolean.
For builds triggered by timer it is ${BUILD_CAUSE_TIMERTRIGGER} which for builds triggered by timer will be set to true.

Comment: But this shouldn't be the case for [jenkins-pipeline], aka [jenkins-workflow], but only for freestyle jobs.So very weird.. probably @Bachu has been using this tag without knowing what it means.

Answer (score 1):

If using pipeline 2.0, you can use:

```
if(manager.logContains("Started by timer")){
        echo "This build was triggered by a timer."
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mean if the build output happened to have the line "Started by timer" then this would evaluate to true? Ex: say my build output spits out the line `Now checking if Started by timer`, wouldn't that cause a false positive?

Comment: Good work around for Jenkins pipeline where currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses() is not permitted due to org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use the [user build vars plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-user-vars-plugin):

```
def buildUser
wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
    buildUser = env.BUILD_USER
}
```

`buildUser` will contain a user name when the pipeline is triggered manually, and null otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can check those information in Jenkins Console output.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the console Output

The first line will be:

Started by user xxx   (if a human started it)

or

Started by an SCM change  (if a change in version control triggered it)

or

Started by timer   (if it was scheduled)